# Express.js: Async issue while API-call

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, express, asynchronous

I really like programming with `node.js` and especially `express.js.` Today I run into the typically async issue. I read a lot about these issues and possible solutions, but what is best practice for express.js?

I tried to transfer the callback approach, but it doesn't work. I have to admit, I am a kind of greenhorn in the field and I would appreciate possibly solutions from the community :).

I think the issue in the following code is, that the function call `getUserDataFromSpotify(cookieAccessToken)` is `async` and the next row can't get the id of the `inputData` variable as fast as the function returns a value.

```
app.get('/landingpage', function(req, res){
  var cookieAccessToken = req.cookies.access_token;
  var inputData = getUserDataFromSpotify(cookieAccessToken);
  res.render('UserProfile', {display_name: inputData.id});
});

function getUserDataFromSpotify(userToken){
 var options = {
   url: 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/me',
   headers: { 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + userToken },
   json: true
 };
 request.get(options, function(error, response, body) {
      console.log(response.statusCode);
      console.log(body);
      return body;
});
}
```

Comment: You are trying to use a async function as a synchronous function which is wrong in in NodeJS.

Comment: Thank's for your comment, Mustafa! Is there any solution that works for API calls in this way?

Comment: I was trying to answer but not possible any more. Try promise, callback or async function structure to resolve the async call first and then do the res.render

Comment: try using call back or promise functionality